# Stored procedure doesn't return rows

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I want to use SQL Server 2014 stored procedure in Report Builder.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getCharacterDetails]
      @id int
     ,@name VARCHAR(200)  = ''  OUTPUT
     ,@level int  = 0 OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @name = name, @level = level
    FROM 
        dbo.Characters 
    WHERE
        id = @id;

    RETURN
END
```

I want to use `@id` as an input parameter and name and level as output only parameters.

When I call the procedure using Report Builder I get no data.

When I execute a query:

```
 exec [dbo].[getCharacterDetails] @id= 1;
```

I also get no result values, only (1 row(s) affected) or Commands completed successfully.
The table Characters contains 1 row with id=1, so the select is correct.

Am I doing it right? Should I be using stored procedures or maybe UDF?

I'm new to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

No, this stored procedure definitely doesn't return rows - because you're capturing the values into **output** parameters.

If you want to **return rows** - do not assign those columns to variables! Just write the select"as is".

So just this *this* `SELECT` statement instead:

```
SELECT 
    name, level
FROM 
    dbo.Characters 
WHERE
    id = @id;
```

and your stored procedure will now return a result set of data.

Comment: This worked in the Management Studio. Thanks. But I still can't see my data in the report builder. I created a data source with parameters [name],[level]. I provide an input parameter [id] and it displays no results.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not in the Stored Procedure, but it's with the report builder...

Comment: There should be only one input to your stored procedure - ID. SP's do work with SSRS

Answer (score 1):

Try running the stored procedure as:

```
 declare @name VARCHAR(200);
 declare @level int;

 exec dbo.getCharacterDetails 1, @name output, @level output;

 select @name, @level;
```

You have to provide the arguments and then look at them afterwards.  That is how `output` parameters work.

If you want the stored procedure to return rows, then don't assign the values, or you can do both.  The body could be:

```
SELECT  @name = name, @level = level
FROM dbo.Characters 
WHERE id = @id;

SELECT @name, @level;
```

And, for such a simple process, you might want just a view or user defined function.

Comment: Why use an UDF or a view? I can't pass input parameters to a view (however i can select from view where ...), What about UDFs? Why are they better than SPs?

Comment: @Asd . . . You can use a UDF in a query.  You can use a stored procedure in a query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getCharacterDetails]
      @id int
     ,@name VARCHAR(200)  = ''  OUTPUT
     ,@level int  = 0 OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        name, level
    FROM 
        dbo.Characters 
    WHERE
        id = @id;

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: Is it a good practice to set values to 0/empty string or NULL for output only parameters if I don't want to take them as input?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is cached, delete the data file (rdl.data) it's in the same folder your rdl is in

Answer (score 0):

The name and level parameters serve no purpose. Remove them.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getCharacterDetails]
  @id int
AS
BEGIN
SELECT 
    name, level
FROM 
    dbo.Characters 
WHERE
    id = @id;

RETURN
END
```

call it like this:

```
EXEC [dbo].[getCharacterDetails] @ID
```

and make sure you map a SSRS parameter to the input parameter @ID in the parameters tab.

If you still don't get anything use SQL Profiler to work out what parameter it's passing in.